# Allocating memory for pointer struct which has pointer members

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read and print using struct pointer which has pointer members. So I am trying to read and print array of double struct pointers.
I tried the folowing but it is giving me error saying "Access violation writing location (somewhere in memory)"

How can I allocate memory dynamically for this?

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct template{
char *name;
int  *birthdate;
int *phoneNum;

} detailsOf;

void inputValue(detailsOf **person, int maxSize);

int main() {

detailsOf **person;
int maxSize = 0, menu = 0;

printf("Max:");
scanf("%d", &maxSize);


person = (detailsOf **)malloc(maxSize * sizeof(detailsOf **));
if (person == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate");
    exit(0);
}
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
    person[i]->name = (char *)calloc(21, sizeof(char ));
    person[i]->birthdate = (int *)calloc(8, sizeof(int ));
    person[i]->phoneNum = (int *)calloc(16, sizeof(int ));
}

inputValue(person, maxSize);

for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
    free(person[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
        free(person[i]->name[j]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        free(person[i]->phoneNum[j]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        free(person[i]->birthdate[j]);
    }
}
    return 0;
}
void inputValue(detailsOf **person, int maxSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
        printf("Name of %d", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", person[i]->name);
          for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
             printf("Birth %d:", i + 1);
             scanf("%d", person[i]->birthdate[j]);
     } 
     for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
         printf("Phone %d:", i + 1);
         scanf("%d", person[i]->phoneNum[k]);
      }
   }
    printf("SUCCESS\n");
}
```

Comment: Please ignore the menu variable.

Comment: Who upvotes these questions? There's no apparent debugging effort, just a chunk of code and a memory access error (at minimum I'd expect the information you'd get from a debugger, i.e. "it crashes in line X because pointer Y is invalid"). This isn't even a [mcve]: It's incomplete (the program requires input, which is not provided) and not minimal (OP says "*please ignore the menu variable*" instead of just removing it from the code if it doesn't matter).

Comment: @melpomene I think it is the person answering to insure the question isn't deleted after they answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If you are hinting at me, then i want to humbly let know, its not me.

Comment: Oh no, no, I was suggesting it may have been me `:)` But @melpomene has a good point. There have been a rash of questions, that fail to meet the MCVE standards or that are duplicates many times over that have been upvoted. Unexplained.

Comment: sorry for that. it is my first time posting question here and i am a beginner so even though I ve been tryin to solve it since yesterday. i couldn't figure it out why. Debugger just said what i mentioned in the descr. Anyways, Sorry @melpomene for the time you spent glancing over my chunk of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
person = (detailsOf **)malloc(maxSize * sizeof(detailsOf **));
```

should be

```
person = malloc(maxSize * sizeof(detailsOf *));
```

Then, this allocated memory to hold pointers to `detailsOf` but you never allocate memory for each `detailsOf`

```
for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
{
   person[i]=malloc(sizeof(detailsOf));
}
```

Also your freeing of memory should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
{
    free(person[i]->name);
    free(person[i]->phoneNum);
    free(person[i]->birthdate);
    free(person[i]);
}
free(person);
```

Remember while freeing just match your `free` calls with `malloc` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Rule is simple -- a pointer is *uninitialized* until it has had a valid address assigned to it, or memory has been allocated within which to store things and the starting address for the new block of memory assigned to it.

You allocate `maxSize` **pointers** for `person`, but then fail to allocate a `struct` for each `person[i]` before allocating for `name`, etc..

So you must allocate a struct, e.g. `pointer[i] = malloc (sizeof *pointer[i])` before attempting to allocate `person[i]->name = calloc(21, sizeof(char ));`, ...

Also note, if you allocate based on the size of the derefernced pointer -- you will never get your allocation wrong, (your allocation of `person` is only correct as the result of happy-accident), instead, e.g.

```
person = malloc (maxSize * sizeof *person);
...
person[i] = malloc (sizeof *person[i]);
```

(and note a `[]` or `->` counts as a dereference)

```
person[i]->name = calloc (21, sizeof *person[i]->name);
```

There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0):

```
person = (detailsOf **)malloc(maxSize * sizeof(detailsOf **));
```

This allocates an array of double pointers to type `detailsOf` with array size as `maxSize`.

`sizeof(detailsOf**)` is the size of an address, it does not give you the size of your user-defined datatype `detailsOf`.

Also, double pointer means, it is an address location which will store the address of another pointer which points to the memory location of `detailsOf`

```
/* if you want to use double pointer then */
detailsOf **dptr;  // two dimensional array of detailsOf */
detailsOf *sptr;   /* one dimentional array of detailsOf */

/* This allocates the memory for storing 3 detailsOf struct data */
sptr = malloc(3 * sizeof(detailsOf)); 
dptr = &sptr;

/* Now to access double ptr */
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    dptr[0][i].birthdate = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    dptr[0][i].birthdate[0] = i; 
    dptr[0][i].birthdate[1] = i + 10; 
    dptr[0][i].birthdate[2] = i + 1990; 
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    printf("%d\\", dptr[0][i].birthdate[0]); 
    printf("%d\\", dptr[0][i].birthdate[1]); 
    printf("%d\n", dptr[0][i].birthdate[2]); 
}

/* Not to free the double pointer,
 * you have to free the inner pointer first then the outer pointers
 * Easy to remember is to free in reverse order of your allocation order
 */
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    free(dptr[0][i].birthdate);
    free(dptr[0]);
    /* free(dptr); this is not needed in this example because
     * dptr is pointer to address of a local variable,
     * but if it points to address of another array of detailOf* 
     * then this free is needed
     */ 
}
```

In your case, you have just an array of pointer and not an array of double pointers.